# A platform for writing custom text, then hear it and try to write it down without mistakes?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, listening, writing

I am searching for a platform where I can add my custom text (1000 words for example) and the platform should hide this text from me and I should be able to hear it only (slowly) and then write the same text only by listening to the audio and then submit my written text when I am done and the platform should mark if I have make any mistakes. Is there such a platform available online or mobile app? It will be very useful for me learning a new language to be able to practice my writing.

Comment: I have never heard of such an application or platform; it sounds like an interesting programming project for computer science students :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing that manually with subtitled videos. When I write the text I hear, I simply hide the subtitles with a piece of paper. I also adjust the video playback speed to what I need, for example 0.75 the normal speed.

When I am ready to correct, I replay the same video and compare the subtitles with my transcription.

Sometimes, the voices and the subtitles don't match exactly, but figuring it out becomes part of my learning process.